# How to check number of pairs elements in array?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to solve a problem but I can't seem to figure out the right way to do it. For example: array []= {1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4} . Here pairs of 1 are 2 and a pair of 3 is 1. So total there is 3 pair. I am trying to solve this. Here is the current code situation.

```
static int PairCounter(int n, int[] ar) {
    int temp_n = 0;

    //store the array range with constrains
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of object: ");
    temp_n = Console.Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
    if((temp_n >= 1) || (temp_n <= 100)){
        n = temp_n;
    }else{
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value less then 100 and greater then 1.");
        temp_n = Console.Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
        if((temp_n >= 1) || (temp_n <= 100)){
            n = temp_n;
        }else{
                Console.WriteLine("Please rerun the code.");
            }
    }
    //Stores Array with constrains
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of array: ");
    int[] arr = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i<= n; i++){
        arr[i] = Console.Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
        if((arr[i] >= 1) || (arr[i] <= 100)){
            ar[i] = arr[i];
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value less then 100 and greater then 1.");
            arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
            if((arr[i] >= 1) || (arr[i] <= 100)){
                ar[i] = arr[i];
            }else{
                    Console.WriteLine("Rerun the code");
                }
        }    
    }

    //copy the array to another array
    int[] array3 = new int[n];
    for(i=0;i<=n; i++)
    {
    array3[i]=ar[i];
    }
    int repeat_counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<=n;i++){
        if(ar[i].Contains(array3[i])){
            repeat_counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciatable.

Comment: "Here pairs of 1 are 2 and a pair of 3 is 1. So total there is 3 pair" Eeeehm, what? I don´t have any clue about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Seems simple enough: Count how often each number appears. Divide by 2 (with integers it will automatically round down). And sum it up. The hardest part should be figuring out when you reached the highest number in that list. But this list does look sorted, so it should be simply looking at the last number.

Comment: is it a school project? because if not (and can be solved using any ways) it can be found with a very simple Linq

Comment: @HimBromBeere: It is two pairs of 1's and one pair of 3's. So three pairs in total. Or at least that is what I read. I guess a mathematical term could be something like unique pairs (so 1, 1, 1, 1 only contains 2 pairs, not in excess of 8 or so).

Comment: something like: `array.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new {x.Key, x.Count() / 2});`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a one liner:

```
var pairs = ii.GroupBy(i => i).Sum(g => g.Count() / 2);
```

But yeah, using linq is cheating in the present circumstances. An easy way to solve this is taking advantage that you are counting ints. You can use an array to keep track of how many instances of any given number you find by using that same number as the index:

```
static int CountPairs(int[] array)
{
    var counter = new int[array.Length];

    foreach (var i in array)
    {
        counter[i] += 1;
    }

    var pairs = 0;

    foreach (var count in counter)
    {
        pairs += count / 2;
    }

    return pairs;
}
```

That should also do the trick.

Of course you could generalize this to work with anything, but a simple array won't work anymore, you'd need something a tad more sophisticated: a dictionary. But the idea is the same as the previous solution; simply keeping track of how many times you see any given item:

```
static int CountPairs<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var counter = new Dictionary<T, int>();

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!counter.TryAdd(item, 1))
            counter[item] += 1;
    }

    var pairs = 0;

    foreach (var count in counter.Values)
    {
        pairs += count / 2;
    }

    return pairs;
}
```

But...meh, once here, its probably better to simply use the linq one-liner ;)

Comment: From question: "So total there is 3 pair".  It looks like OP wants to count groups where more than one item (I'm not sure). If so, you need to replace `Sum` with `Count(g => g.Count() > 1)`. In any case +1, I'm love one liner solutions )

Answer (score 0):

with Linq its very simple:

```
var result = array.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new {num = x.Key, count = x.Count() / 2});
foreach(var item in result)
    Consolve.WriteLine($"{item.count} pair(s) of {item.num}");
```

To get the total number of pairs:

```
int total = array.GroupBy(x => x).Sum(x => x.Count());
Consolve.WriteLine($"{total} pair(s) in total");
```